# Message.getAllChats Telegram bot

Tags: php, node.js, lua, telegram

Well, I was trying to make a bot that can send to me all the chats that I have in telegram with its ID's. I cannot understand the Telegram API documentation and there's like 2 or 3 examples using Lua and PHP.

At this point, I can send messages with the bot, send products with the sendInvoice too, but I dont know how to use the messages.getAllChats method.

I think I can apply this method into the node language but im not sure at all.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: what is there not to understand? it returns a list of all chats except those you provided an except id for. please be more specific about your question and share some code.